# About the Buddha Preaching that we Humans are Aliens

Tags: theravada, reference-request

What I have heard is, the Buddha has preached that we Humans are the Evolution of Alien life which had arrived on earth many years before
Could this be correct and did he preach so and in which SUTRA is it recorded ?
Thank you

Answer (score 4):

The Sutta you are looking for is [Agganna sutta](https://suttacentral.net/dn27/en/sujato).
In the second part of the Sutta, the Buddha tells the story of how human beings came to dwell on Earth.

> The Buddha said that sooner or later, after a very long time, there
>   would come a time when the world(universe) shrinks. At a time of contraction,
>   beings are mostly born in the Abhassara Brahma world. And there they
>   dwell, mind-made, feeding on delight, self-luminous, moving through
>   the air, glorious — and they stay like that for a very long time. But
>   sooner or later, after a very long period, this world begins to expand
>   again. At a time of expansion, the beings from the Abhassara Brahma
>   world, having died from there, are mostly reborn in this world. Here
>   they dwell, mind-made, feeding on delight, self-luminous, moving
>   through the air, glorious — and they stay like that for a very long
>   time...

Comment: That Sutta is so intriguing. :-)